# Oracle: How to efficiently copy a table from one schema to another on a different database and server

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a large table (3.5MM records) that I need to copy from one schema/database to another schema/database.  I tried TOAD's copy data from table feature, but got errors and it never fully copied, in part because the connection keeps getting dropped.  I'm trying the object copy feature of SQLDeveloper, and after 11 minutes, it's still copying.  I tried the SQLPlus COPY statement but got a syntax error (help needed).  I'm still open to extracting the data as INSERT statements that I can just run directly.

1) SQLPLUS Copy as follows:

```
copy from  report_new/mypassword@(DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.15.15.20)(PORT=1541))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=STAGE))) to report/mypassword@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.18.22.25)(PORT=1550))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DEV))) CREATE USER_USAGE_COUNT USING SELECT * FROM _USER_USAGE_COUNT
```

The above gives me

```
SQL> start copy_user_count_table.sql
SP2-0758: FROM clause missing username
```

2) I tried TOAD
The TOAD "Copy data to another schema" fails due to the connection getting 
dropped. I set the commit threshold first to 5000 then to 500.

3) I'm trying SQLDeveloper's copy function, but I think it's not going to finish anytime soon and it gives me no real progress indications. For all I know, it could be hung but that it just doesn't want to tell me.

4) I thought about creating a datalink, but I don't have the authority to create one, and it's in a corporate environment wherein the DBA's don't respond in under 3 days.

Todo: Should I write my own Java code to just do this one record at a time?? I shouldn't have to do this, but somehow it's easier to send a man to the moon than to copy data from one schema to another.

Comment: I'd say that data pump export & import is the right way to do that. These utilities are designed to *move data around*.

Comment: Try the EZ Connect syntax: copy from report_new/mypassword@10.15.15.20:1541/STAGE to report/mypassword@10.18.22.25:1550/DEV CREATE USER_USAGE_COUNT USING SELECT * FROM _USER_USAGE_COUNT

Comment: @btpys Can you tell me what I did wrong with the copy command I had above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the copy command of `sqlcl` which is part of newer SQLdeveloper releases. The `sqlcl` is found in the `Sqldeveloper\bin` directory and is named sql.exe (Windows) or sql (Unix/Linux/Mac). The steps to follow are:

1. Connect to Destination database with sqlcl

```sql
sql username/password@destindationdb
```

2. Use the copy command

```sql
copy from username@sourcedatabase create newtablename using select * from sourcetable;
```

Comment: Can you tell me what I did wrong with the copy command I had above?

Comment: @Woodsman I think the issue is the tns-synax in the connect. I've tried your example with the connectstring with tns-syntax in sqlplus `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=` and got the same error `SP2-0758: FROM clause missing username`. With EZ connect syntax `user/password@host:port/Servicename` it is running correctly in sqlplus.

Comment: Thanks. It was too late and I couldn't see the difference between this ez (more sensible) syntax vs that TNS syntax. My mistake.